# Find out unique of variable with two dimension

Tags: sql-server

I have a table "production" like that:

```
|company | Product | Model|   
A          Printer   1200
B          Lap       1100
C          PC        1500
C          Lap       1300
A          Printer   1800
```

I want to find out company who produce only 1 type product,
 and the number of those models exceeds 1.

I try so much. But I just select the company product 1 type.

Pls help me.

Comment: sorry i have some error tabkle's name is production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select company from production
group by company 
having count(distinct model)>1 and count(distinct product)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select company from production
group by company
having count(distinct product) = 1
and count(distinct model) > 1
```

See a demo fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8a11/3

Comment: you need add more " and count(models)>1 ". It will be right

Comment: Yep, that's done now. See the edited answer with a demo fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
select company from product 
where company in 
(select company from product group by company having count(distinct product)=1)
group by company 
having count(distinct model)>1
```